# htaccess GET variables in URL after rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a .htaccess file that needs to see the directories as 1 variable: ex. `http://example.com/this-is-page-one/sub-dir` will pass `this-is-page-one/sub-dir` as a variable to PHP.

I have this at the moment:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#  Page rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /page.php?url=$1

#  Add trailing slash to urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

This works fine as long as you type a trailing slash behind the URL. But as you can see the htaccess will put a trailing slash behind the URL for you. When that happens, it automatically puts the `?url=` variable behind it.

ec. `http://example.com/this-is-page-one/sub-dir/?url=this-is-page-one/sub-dir`

Does someone see what I do wrong?

Comment: Put the second set of condition and rules before the first.

Comment: You are the best Jessica! What a quick and right response, you made my day! :D If you put it in the answer column I will set it to the right answer.

Comment: Thanks! I posted it as a comment first because it was mostly a logic-based guess, glad it was the right one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the second set of condition and rule before the first:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#  Add trailing slash to urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

#  Page rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /page.php?url=$1
```